# random element from array in c

Tags: c, arrays, random, int

How can I select a random element from a character array in c ?

For instance:

```
char *array[19];

array[0] = "Hi";


array[1] = "Hello";
```

etc

I am looking for something like array[rand], where rand is the random integer number between o and the array's length(in this case 20) like 1, 2, 3 , 19 etc.

Comment: You're looking after [`rand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand)

Comment: try `array[(int) (20 * rand())]` where 20 is the length of the array.

Comment: where 20 is the length of the array, I suppose?

Comment: maybe `char* array[20];`

Comment: Crud, forgot this is C - need to scale rand() by the maximum integer.

Comment: So, to be clear, `20 * rand()` is not correct. Use `rand() % 20`. However, if your array is 20 elements long you need to fix your variable declaration! You're only allocating 19 elements there.

Comment: @svk No, don't use `%` because the results can be non-uniform.  Multiplying a U(0,1) value times 20 and flooring will give an int from 0 to 19, i.e., 20 elements all set for zero-based array indices.

Comment: Your example assignments will not work; what you're defining is a array of characters, not strings.

Comment: The array should be a pointer, got it.

Comment: What @pjs is refereing to is this issue from the linux man pages: "The versions of rand() and srand() in the Linux C Library use the same random number generator as random(3) and srandom(3), so the lower-order bits should be as random as the higher-order bits. However, on older rand() implementations, and on current implementations on different systems, the lower-order bits are much less random than the higher-order bits. Do not use this function in applications intended to be portable when good randomness is needed. (Use random(3) instead.)"

Comment: If there's a concern about the quality of randomness `rand()` is probably not the best PRNG to be using in the first place. Using `rand()`, but dividing by `RAND_MAX`, then scaling by 20.0, then truncating, is a middle ground between convenience and quality which accomplishes neither.

Comment: My earlier quote suggests that if your platform provides `random()` it may be better than `rand()` if you're using the `%` method (and equally goos as using (int)(U(0,1)*20).

Comment: @svk - `rand()/RAND_MAX` = 0, as they're both ints. You're better off multiplying by 20.0 first and then dividing by RAND_MAX.

Comment: True, my phrasing was sloppy. In any case my point was that if you care enough about quality to do this, you probably want to use a better PRNG (such as `random` if it's available on your platform).

Comment: @MichaelAnderson No, pjs is referring to the fact that `rand() % 20` doesn't exactly model a uniform distribution if RAND_MAX is not one less than a multiple of 20. Some values are more likely than others. Compare with rolling a 6-sided die and taking the result modulo 5: possible results are 1,2,3,4,0,1. 1 is twice as likely as the other results.

Comment: @Casey If thats the bias he's referring to, then scaling `rand()` to U(0,1) then scaling by 20 will not help - By the pigeonhole principle you get exactly the same amount of bias. The bias due to this is < (20/RAND_MAX) and since the standard guarantees RAND_MAX > 32767 you're looking at a maximum bias of less than 0.06%. ( 32760 values occur 1638 times, and 7 values occur 1639 times). If this bias is too large for you (and your RAND_MAX=32760) you need to either reject those 7 values (rejection sampling - which is unbiased), or combine more than one call to rand() to get more "random" bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start things off, since you have an array of strings, not of characters, you have to declare it as `char* array[19];`

Then, you can declare the following (always useful) macro

`#define ARR_SIZE(arr) ( sizeof((arr)) / sizeof((arr[0])) )`

Last, you can choose `arr[rand() % ARR_SIZE(arr)]` (while keeping in mind that performing `%` on `rand()` is **not** the proper way to do get a random number within a range.

Comment: On most systems, you will get the same answer each time you run the program unless you seed the random number generator with a different value each time.  Check out [`srand()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/srand.html), but be aware that getting a decent seed is actually rather hard.  And the
[`drand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) family of PRNG functions is quite useful too, though you still have the seeding problem.

Comment: That is a correct comment, however I was referring to the issue of selecting a random number within a range of numbers in such a manner as to remain evenly distributed.

Answer (score 2):

```
int n = rand()%20;
printf("%s\n", array[n]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try array[rand() % ARRAY_LEN] but you are going to get a single char and not a `char*`

and when you are doing array[0] = "Hi"; it's not correct since you are assigning to a single `char` a `char*`

or turn your `char array[20]` into a `char *array[20]` and you can assign a string of characters

Comment: You are correct. I was getting seg fault before I modify the array into a pointer. (Upvote, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

What you propose is the best solution there is - choose a random index and then use the element at this index. If your question is how to get a random integer, use the built-in function `rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using rand in the c library stdlib.h

You can get  a random number like this:

char random_elem = array[rand()%20];

and you can print it out like this:

printf("%d",array[rand()%20]);

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but this question already has few good-quality answers and your answer adds nothing new. How about focusing on some [unanswered C questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c)?