# rand function c args

Tags: c, random

I have a multi task application based on DTW(Dynamic Time Wrapping) that has this code line:

```
void randPattern(int in[SIZE][SIZE]){
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++){
            in[i][j] = abs(rand(23, 2, 100)%5000);
        }
    }
}
```

So, when i tried to compile with "arm-none-eabi-gcc" this returns:

```
error: too many arguments to function 'rand'
```

What i can do to solve this message or what i can use instead this function.
If someone have an explanation...
Thanks for attention

Comment: Function `int rand(void)` has no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) from [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/), the `rand` function has the following prototype:

```
int rand (void);
```

and you get an `int` between 0 and `RAND_MAX`. You must pass no argument to the function.

By the way, don't forget to initialize the function at the begginning of your program by calling :

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

If you need to choose a random element from an array, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215242/random-element-from-array-in-c) may be the right place to look for.